# How to get important words using LGBM feature importance and Tfidf vectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn, lightgbm, tfidfvectorizer

I am working a Kaggle dataset that predicts a price of an item using its description and other attributes. [Here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercari-price-suggestion-challenge/overview) is the link to the competition. As part of an experiment, I am currently, only using an item's description to predict its price. The description is free text and I use sklearn's Tfidf's vectorizer with a bi-gram and max features set to 60000 as input to a lightGBM model.

After training, I would like to know the most influential tokens for predicting the price. I assumed lightGBM's `feature_importance` method will be able to give me this. This will return a 60000 dim numpy array, whose index I can use to retrieve the token from the Tfidf's vectorizer's vocab dictionary.

Here is the code:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), max_features=60000)
x_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(train_df['text'].values.astype('U'))
x_valid = vectorizer.transform(valid_df['text'].values.astype('U'))

idx2tok = {v: k for k, v in vectorizer.vocabulary_.items()}
features = [f'token_{i}' for i in range(len(vectorizer.vocabulary_))]
get_tok = lambda x, idxmap: idxmap[int(x[6:])]

lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(x_train, y_train)
lgb_valid = lgb.Dataset(x_valid, y_valid, reference=lgb_train)

gbm = lgb.train(lgb_params, lgb_train, num_boost_round=10, valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_valid], early_stopping_rounds=10, verbose_eval=True)
```

The model trains, however, after training when I call `gbm.feature_importance()`, I get a sparse array of integers, that really doesn't make sense to me:

```
fi = gbm.feature_importance()
fi[:100]
array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
      dtype=int32)

np.unique(fi)
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 33, 34, 38, 45],
      dtype=int32)
```

I'm not sure how to interpret this. I thought that earlier indices of the feature importance array will have higher value and thus tokens corresponding to that index in the vectorizer's vocab will be more important/influential than other tokens. Is this assumption wrong? How do I get the most influential/important terms that determines the model outcome? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.